# Use Launch Image for Launch Screen

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode7

using xcode 7 I wanna to create a Launch Screen with the same image for all iPhones.

In the application main target -> General -> App Icones and Launch Images -> Launch Image Source I have selected the "LaunchImage"

In the assets I created a LaunchImage (App Icons & Launch Images->New iOS Launch Image) and I put all the images applicable to the various devices.

When I start my app there isn't launch image. Anyone know why? Thanks to all

Comment: does it show any warning for launch image? and what is the value in the `Launch screen file` did you clear that?

Comment: There isn't any warning. 
And explain more the other question, wich kind of value?
You can download my project "Launch.zip" in my repository:

https://github.com/Volpesio/Launch.git

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new. Now it's ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this code:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(fullscreenNamed name: String)  {
        switch UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height {
        case 480: //iPhone 4/4s
            self.init(named: "\(name)-700@2x.png")
        case 568: //iPhone 5/5s
            self.init(named: "\(name)-700-568h@2x.png")
        case 667: //iPhone 6/6s
            self.init(named: "\(name)-800-667h@2x.png")
        case 736: //iPhone 6+/6s+
            self.init(named: "\(name)-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png")
        default:
            self.init(named: name)
        }
    }
}
```

I take in "LaunchImage" the right image for the device screen in use.

@Pyro, thanks for your help

Comment: it's great that you find the answer that you wanted, but there is no need of putting the same answer in the 3 different posts,you can make a single post with for any question and post the answer in the particular post else that can be count as duplicate sometimes

Comment: Where did you used the extension? As. launch screen have no controller

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment remove the `Launch screen file` value from the Launch(application main target) -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images -> Launch screen file, so it will be likes this

[image: Launch image]

After that you run it, it should be there

Comment: I'm sorry, before I didn't understood Now It's functional, thank you very much

Comment: Here https://github.com/Volpesio/Launch.git (Launch.zip) is my idea of implementation to ensure that the LaunchImage remains visible after the Launch Screen. But on some iPhone the picture is distorted! because? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @AlessioVolpe generally we should not use Launch image assets inside the application, in your case if you print the frame of image after you assign the image it will return 320*480 and after you assign the screen width and height the image is enlarged to fit according to the size which causes the issue, for the asset to be used in app you should create separate image and provide 1x,2x,3x images

Comment: great, now I understand!
I had thought about using the same images of LaunchImage for I save the memory.
Ok but what image for 1x for 2x for 3x?
iPhone 4/4s 640x960, iPhone 5/5s 640x1136, iPhone 6/6s 750x1334, iPhone 6/6s Plus 1080x1920 ?

I would like to have the same effect the Launch Screen, you not should see the change of image.

Comment: i have a LaunchScreen.storyboard, how i am going to put a Launch image source to that?